# Vertical align text in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I've this situation :

```
<div class="row">       
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center" id="testo-centrale">
        <h1>IL BOX PIU' GRANDE DELLA TOSCANA<BR>CON AFFILIAZIONE CROSSFIT INC.</h1>
        <h2>Prova Prova prova prova</h2>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#testo-centrale {height:500px;}
```

The texts, `h1` and `h2`, are centered in `horizontal` but i want also in `vertical` !

Thanks guys !

Comment: Use bootstrap 4 - think they may have a class for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox with `align-items: center;` to center vertically.

```css
#testo-centrale {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center" id="testo-centrale">
    <h1>IL BOX PIU' GRANDE DELLA TOSCANA<BR>CON AFFILIAZIONE CROSSFIT INC.</h1>
    <h2><?php the_field('testo_centrale_chi_siamo'); ?></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but not totally.
the h1 is on the left and the h2 on the right, instead h1 above and h2 below.

Comment: @AntonioCarbone ah sorry, (I mean _lo siento_!) I can't read the text so I didn't notice that. Just needs `flex-direction: column;` - updated my answer.